# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined in WP 5.5

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-5.5

I have WordPress website which I updated to version 5.5

Now I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at jquery.tools18.min.js?ver=10.2.2:281
    at jquery.tools18.min.js?ver=10.2.2:358
(index):738 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):738)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

I tried to apply this fix:

```
https://bootstrapcreative.com/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined/
```

by adding this into header.php of the template that I use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    
    <script>
       
        jQuery.browser = {};
        (function () {
            jQuery.browser.msie = false;
            jQuery.browser.version = 0;
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
                jQuery.browser.msie = true;
                jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
            }
        })();
    </script>
        
</head>
```

But it's not working. I get the same error. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that jQuery is added to the footer of your site, not in the header.

Ideally, you would create a javascript file in your theme that you can include and specify it is dependent on jQuery; that way, you can be certain your code will always be loaded *after* jQuery, whether it's loaded in the header or the footer.

1. So place everything you have between your  tags in a separate file in your theme: let's call it "scripts.js"
2. In your theme's functions.php file, you want to load that script as a dependent of jQuery:

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_name_enqueue_scripts');
   function my_theme_name_enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-name-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts.js', array('jquery'));
   }

That 3rd argument to the `wp_enqueue_script` function call is an array of other scripts yours depends on.

For a full list of script handles/names WordPress makes available to you, [see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)